# Trying to get the vertex-edge structure present in a MultiPolygon object (the "shapely" module in Python)

Tags: python, shapely

Is there an elegant way to get the graph connectivity structure (vertices, edges) for a MultiPolygon object in shapely (python)?

Comment: I think you can get the vertex (in order) from a Polygon with `list(polygon.exterior.coords)`

Comment: @RickyA is correct, and if you want to do some graph analysis, then I'd suggest reading the vertices into a graph created with a network analysis package such as networkX.